# Is it preferable to handle transactions and errors in ASP.NET or in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, transactions

We're having a bit of a debate around the office here about exception handling, transactions and SQL errors.

We have a lot of stored procedures and all of them were created from boilerplate code so every one has a Try... Catch block in it.  Many (though not all) create their own transactions if the @@NESTLEVEL = 1.

One argument is to handle both the transaction and any errors at the ASP.NET level, removing all the try/catch from stored procedures, like this:

```
    Dim sConnectionString As String = "<some connection string>"
    Using oConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
        Dim oCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("StoredProcWithNoTransaction", oConn)
        Dim oTrans As SqlClient.SqlTransaction

        oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        oTrans = oConn.BeginTransaction
        Try
            oConn.Open()

            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            oTrans.Commit()
        Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
            oTrans.Rollback()
            If ex.Number = 1205 Then

            ElseIf ex.Number = 50001 Then

            ElseIf ex.Number = 50002 Then

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            oTrans.Rollback()

        End Try
    End Using
```

The other is to let the stored procedure handle the errors and the transaction
CREATE MyProc 
    @iSomeID int
AS

```
TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --<UPDATE, DELETE, do stuff>

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE   NVARCHAR(2048),

    @ERROR_PROCEDURE NVARCHAR(126),
    @ERROR_NUMBER    INTEGER,
    @ERROR_LINE      INTEGER,
    @ERROR_SEVERITY  INTEGER,
    @ERROR_STATE     INTEGER,
    @TRAN_STATE      INTEGER,
    @TRAN_COUNT      INTEGER

    SET @TRAN_STATE      = XACT_STATE();
    SET @TRAN_COUNT      = @@TRANCOUNT;
    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE   = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
    SET @ERROR_NUMBER    = ERROR_NUMBER()
    SET @ERROR_LINE      = ERROR_LINE()
    SET @ERROR_SEVERITY  = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    SET @ERROR_STATE     = ERROR_STATE()

    IF @TRAN_STATE <> 0 AND @TRAN_COUNT <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    IF @ERROR_NUMBER  = 1205
        BEGIN
            PRINT('Something')
        END
    ELSE IF @ERROR_NUMBER  = 50001
        BEGIN
            SELECT This FROM here WHERE there=1
        END
    ELSE IF @ERROR_NUMBER  = 50001
        BEGIN
            SELECT This FROM here WHERE there=1
        END

    RAISERROR (@ERROR_NUMBER,@ERROR_SEVERITY,@ERROR_STATE)  

END CATCH
```

The question here is: Which is the right way?  Would catching an error or deadlock at the page level create performance issues?

I’ve seen lots of articles on “how” to handle transactions errors in both situations, but what’s the best practice on where it’s best to handle them?

Comment: Just as a hint to what my opinion on this is: Do you *like* T-SQL as a programming language? Do you want to have more T-SQL or more C#? (Question is either to broad or opinion-bases, I'm afraid).

Answer (score -1):

Go for the one which will be easy at maintenance time. I think writing every sp this way is complicate to understand for others and handling it server side is best option. So for me option one is the way to go.